# Serving multiple django-sites on the same domain /es /en /pt

Tags: django, django-sites

Is it posible to serve an app in two diferent sites, on the same domain?

These are the requisites of waht i'm trying to:

- Server the same app in to diferente languages
- The URL would be something like:  www.domain.com/es
                                   www.domain.com/en
- The app would be abble to create diferent contents for each "site"
    The admin will be able to create diferent contents  in diferent languages an publish them on  each "site"

  - The app will share the same "template" (if posible) with translations.

I'm quite sure the "django-sites" is designed for that, but i can't find the doc to check if a site can be accesed fron a  subdirectory.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of many new features available in [django 1.4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-url-patterns).

Answer (score 0):

[`django-cms`](https://www.django-cms.org/) has support for multiple languages exactly like you have described. It also is very extensible making is simple to add functionality for your particular website.